# vectors passing through plane

Tags: calculus

Find the point where the line passing through $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ -1 \\ 5 \end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix} 0 \\ 4 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ intersects the plane $2x + y + z = 1.$

Find the point of intersection between the line connecting $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 3 \\ 6 \end{pmatrix}$ to $\begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 2 \\ 3 \end{pmatrix}$ and the line connecting $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ to $\begin{pmatrix} \phantom -3 \\ \phantom -0 \\ -1 \end{pmatrix}.$

Three different times I set one of the parameters to zero and solved the system of equations. I get a point say Q that lies on the intersection line. So now I have two points P and Q that I know are lying in the looked for plane. So I get a vector PQ and take the cross product of PQ and the direction vector of the line of intersection. I did not look for the third point since the direction vector of the intersection line is parallel to the looked for plane. However, I do not get the answer that is in the book.

Comment: What is the answer you get? Can you add your working to the question? It is easier to then see and point our your mistake.

Comment: I think I am doing it entirely wrong actually, could you give a pointer on where to begin?

Comment: What is the equation of the line that you get? Let's start from there.

Comment: would the normal vector be (-2 5 -3) for the first one? I don't know how to find the equation of the line

Comment: Yes or you can write  $(2,  -5, 3)$ so equation of line is $(0, 4, 2) + (2,  -5,  3) t \ $.

Comment: Now how can your express $x, y, z$? Take those and plug in the equation of the plane. That should give you value of $t$ at intersection from which you can find the point of intersection.

Comment: I got ( 1 2 -1), could you help me with the plug in part? sorry, never did this before!

Comment: What is $(1, 2, -1)$? How did you get that?

Comment: For equation of line you take one of the points on the line and the vector. So equation of the line is $(0, 4, 2) + (2,  -5,  3) t $ which means $x = 0 + 2t, y = 4-5t, z = 2 + 3t$. Now put these values in the equation of the plane. What value do you get for $t$?

Comment: 2(0+2t)+(4-5t)+(2+3t)=1. t=-5/2

Comment: Yes that is all. Now put $t = -5/2$ back in $x, y, z$ and that is the intersection point of the line and the plane.

Comment: Now for second question, please find equation of both lines similarly. Use two different scalar variables for them - for one line, use $s$ and for the other $t$. Equate their $x, y$ and $z$ components to find $s$ and $t$ at the intersection. When you are done, please edit the question and add your solution there. We can validate.